# Data Analysis, find the best city for given individuals

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, model, recommender-system

I'm trying to solve a data analysis question where I'm given data on ~1000 cities. For each city, I have: the average property tax, rating of schools nearby, crime rate, avg number of rooms per appt in X suburb, median value of homes, and some more metrics like this.

**I'm tasked with trying to help a family of 4 (2 young children and 45 year old parents) help figure out which cities they should consider living in.**

Does anyone have any tips on what models / approaches I should use to tackle this issue? I was at first thinking of using some sort of regression model (linear regression?), but I'm not completely sure how to fit such a model, since I don't have a Y-label of "good" or "bad" for a specific suburb given its features. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: See https://www.datarevenue.com/en-blog/building-a-city-recommender-for-nomads